# Avoid Thread has already been started exception (Android)

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, surfaceview

```
    java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
        at java.lang.Thread.checkNotStarted(Thread.java:849)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1059)
        at com.name.MainActivity$MenuView$1.surfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:496)
```

How can I avoid this? I have an inner class `MenuView` which extends `SurfaceView`. It updates a canvas on a thread. `onSurfaceCreated()` I start the thread, and `onSurfaceDestroyed()` I call `thread.join()` to stop the thread. However, if the Google Play Sign in window pops up, and I press the home button while it is in focus, and reopen the app. I get a force close error and the exception that I posted above.

```
holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                allow_thread_to_run = true;
                boolean retry = true;
                while (retry) {
                    if (t!=null && !t.isAlive()) {
                        t.start();
                        retry = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                allow_thread_to_run = false;
                boolean retry = true;
                if(t!=null && t.isAlive()) {
                    while (retry) {
                        try {
                            t.join();
                            retry = false;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

So why does this Google Play window coming into focus cause my thread to start twice. From what I see, my setup has the necessary check `isAlive()` to make sure to avoid this!

Comment: You're not reusing the same Thread instance, right? You cannot start() a single Thread object more than once, even if it has finished  - you must create a completely new Thread instance and start that.

Comment: See also https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Comment: I am also under the impression that a new thread is required for every start()

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @adelphus's view.If you care for the code of Thread calss,you will find that.Every Thread object has a flag that reflects whether this Thread has already been started.

```
boolean hasBeenStarted = false;
```

Once you invoke start() method,it will check the state and change if it is false,otherwise throw an exception like what you have got.see,

```
public synchronized void start() {
    checkNotStarted();

    hasBeenStarted = true;

    nativeCreate(this, stackSize, daemon);
}
```

later,the state will never be changed. When you invoke start() again,it will throw an exception.